# How can I block texts on android 4.4.4 (Moto G)?

Tags: sms, motorola-moto-g, sms-blocking

I'm always getting spam texts and I am sick of regularly losing a couple seconds of my life to these assholes when I hear the message sound and check my phone.

How can I block them?  I would prefer not to use an app that requires access to a bunch of my info.

I looked online and I found some instructions that simply don't work:
http://www.mobiany.com/how-to-block-sms-and-mms-messages-on-the-motorola-moto-g.html
http://www.wikihow.com/Block-Android-Text-Messages

And my carrier can't do this for me.

Is there a built-in way?

Or do I need to download an app?  If so, which one is good?

Comment: If it's the same person just select the number, navigate to the contact section and there should be "block this number etc.", otherwise I'd suggest $15/year ESET as security and has a good sms filter rule.

Comment: Yeah there isn't.  I don't know why.